# Is it possible to put a jupyter notebook cell in VSCode in interactive mode so that it runs the cell when its contents change

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I'm looking for a way to put a jupyter notebook cell in VSCode in interactive mode so that it runs the cell when its contents change without having to run it explicitly.

If there's no existing solution, is it somehow possible to automate executing the cell periodically or does the VSCode jupyter lab integration offer some scripting hooks?

Alternatively, is there a possibility to explicitly execute a cell without loosing the cell focus and its current cursor position? CTRL+Enter directly doesn't work; the tabulator key needs to be pressed four times additionally to get back to the cell.

Comment: and what do you want to happen while you're editing the cell? for it to keep re-running every time you add or remove a character?

Comment: @starball almost like that. [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) implements it very well. There are at least two ways; either cancel and restart the execution on every keypress or (re)start a countdown on every keypress which then executes the cell when it reaches zero.

Comment: yes, that's called a "debounce"

Answer (score 0):

The last time (that I know of) a feature-request like this getting raised, it ended with a comment from a maintainer (Rob Lourens) like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12998#issuecomment-1491114822):

> Sorry, I'm not a fan of an auto-run feature. Re-running a cell can be destructive, slow, etc, I don't think it should ever happen without a user action

And that's a good point. I suppose you could try raising the feature-request "again", but you'd have to actually have to address that concern with reasoning (maybe about use-cases), or with design changes (perhaps a setting to explicitly enable it, or configurable debounce). If you do end up raising a new issue ticket, please comment here with a link to it, or edit the link into this answer post.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by googling "`github vscode jupyter OR notebook issues run cell automatically`".

Comment: I see you know it's called debounce (^^)b  How to argue with (Robs) personal preference? Seems like "I'm not a fan" is telling all there is needed to know. I guess a fork is the easier option.